# Converting GUI-application into .exe-file with cx_Freeze: no plugin found for toolkit qt4

Tags: python, qt, traits, cx-freeze, mayavi

My program contains mayavi, traits and pyqt5 elements in order to visualize something in 3D.
I tried to convert my GUI-Application with cx_Freeze and it created the exe-file ,but running it I got the error:

```
no traitsui.toolkits plugin found for toolkit qt4
```

After some google and stackoverflow research I figured out that it might has something to do with my environment: 
see [creating standalone exe using pyinstaller with mayavi import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50337382/creating-standalone-exe-using-pyinstaller-with-mayavi-import)

According to the suggestions in further google research I added these lines to the top of my code:

```
import imp
try:
    imp.find_module('pyside') # test if PySide if available
except ImportError:
    os.environ['QT_API'] = 'pyqt' # signal to pyface that PyQt4 should be used
```

Following the discussing in the stackoverflow-thread I end up with downloading "Jannick"'s executable. Than I removed the line in my code which is responsible for adding the mayavi scene to the GUI (for testing purposes):

```
    self.ui = Visualization().edit_traits(parent=self,
                                           kind='subpanel').control
```

Visualization() is the class where I do the actual visualization with mayavi... Then I executed cx_Freeze, my setup.py is:

```
import sys
import os
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\\Albo\Anaconda3\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\\Albo\Anaconda3\\tcl\\tk8.6"
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import cx_Freeze.hooks

build_exe_options = {"packages": ['pygments.lexers', 'tvtk.pyface.ui.qt4','pkg_resources._vendor',
                    'mayavi', 'traits', 'traitsui', 'sip',
                    'traitlets','tvtk.vtk_module','traits.api','traitsui.api','os','gui','gui.gui_mayavi', 'tvtk.vtk_module',
                                  'pyface.qt','pyface.qt.QtGui','pyface.qt.QtCore','numpy'],
                     "includes":['gui','gui.gui_mayavi','mayavi','PyQt5'],
                    }


executables = [
    Executable('main.py', targetName='main.exe',base = 'Win32GUI',)
]

setup(name='main',
      version='1.0',
      description='',
      executables=executables,
      options={"build_exe":build_exe_options},
      )
```

Now I had a new error, which is:

```
RuntimeError: No pyface.toolkits plugin found for toolkit qt4
```

Now something strange happened... I copied from "Jannick"s project the pyface folder and replaced in in my build (which has been created from cx_Freeze). My exe-file was running without any problems! I was very happy and I thought okay I just add the line which is for the visualization again and then I copy again the pyface folder and it will run. But now I get an error again which I cannot understand at all:

```
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\xxx\xxx.py", line 300, in initUI
    rightlayout.addWidget(self.ui)
TypeError: addWidget(self, QWidget, stretch: int = 0, alignment: Union[Qt.Alignment, Qt.AlignmentFlag] = Qt.Alignment()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'PySide.QtGui.QWidget'
```

I also realized that I cannot run the script from console but from spyder it's no problem. I think it has still something to do with the environment because if I remove the lines at the top of the code, it works again...

Comment: It looks like you're mixing PyQt and PySide.

Comment: Maybe try to remove the pyside import test and directly go for os.environ['QT_API'] = 'pyqt'. I am not completely sure anymore but it might be possible that I changed some code in pyface, which you are using now.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. I removed the pyside lines and I tried to go with your suggested environment. But after that my script didn't run until I changed to os.environ['QT_API'] = 'pyqt5'. Then I tried to build an executable using cx_freeze with the posted setup.py. It build the exe without errors but when I try to run the exe I get the errormessage: "RuntimeError: No traitsui.toolkits plugin found for toolkit null"

Comment: @Jannick: I downgraded the packages you suggested in your thread: mayavi 4.5.0+vtk71, traits 4.6.0, pyface 5.1.0 and traitsui 5.1.0. But when I try to run my script I get this error now: ImportError: No module named 'vtkCommonCorePython'
Do you have vtk installed properly?
VTK (and build instructions) can be obtained from http://www.vtk.org. I am still using pyqt5. What version of pyqt did you use?

Comment: @roflcopter122 I use pyqt4 because there are still some issues of mayavi with pyqt5 as far as I know. The error ImportError: No module named 'vtkCommonCorePython' Do you have vtk installed properly? indicates that the vtk version does not match your mayavi build. Try to uninstall both explicitely with pip uninstall vtk/mayavi and install them from scratch.

Comment: Okay I try to reinstall the packages. Is it a big deal to downgrade pyqt?

Comment: @roflcopter122 you can have pyqt4 and pyqt5 alongside each other

Comment: @Jannick did you also have problems with QtWidgets ? Using PyQt4 I get the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt4.QtWidgets' ? After a little bit google I figured out that PyQt4’s QtGui module has been split into PyQt5’s QtGui, QtPrintSupport and QtWidgets modules. Therefor I changed PyQt4.QtWidgets to PyQt4.QtGui. Now I don't get any error when I run my script but the strange thing is that nothing happened... My GUI doesn't display at all... Slowly I am getting very desperate ^^ Maybe you had a similar case ?

Comment: When I run the script in spyder after a certain time I get the message from console: Kernel died, restarting...

Comment: @roflcopter122 Just a wild guess: Try to change the line where you instantiate QApplication from app = QtGui.QApplication() to app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()

Comment: That's how it was before when I used pyqt5... Another question. If I import QApplication like: from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication. Do I still need to write QtGui.QApplication.instance() ?

Comment: @Jannick I am still struggling with getting my script running with pyqt4. I completely reinstall python and all packages from sketch. Now it is working with pyqt without errors. When I change all the pyqt5 imports to pyqt4 and run the script from cmd again nothing happens. When I run the script from spyder I get the error: "ImportError: Importing PyQt4 disabled by IPython, which has already imported an Incompatible QT Binding: pyqt5". So I guess the issue has something to do with the backend? I set it with the line: 'os.environ['ETS_TOOLKIT'] = 'qt4''.

Comment: @roflcopter122 Do you have both line os.environ['QT_API'] = 'pyqt' and os.environ['ETS_TOOLKIT'] = 'qt4' ?

Comment: @Jannick yes I do have this two lines.

Comment: Which version of Python and `cx_Freeze` are you using?

Comment: Hi I am using cx_freeze 5.1.1.

Comment: People I finally solved the secret!! I just reinstalled pyface (version 5.1) and then it worked. Thank you for all the help!!

Comment: Great. Please consider adding an answer with your solution and mark it as accepted so that it becomes more visible to others potentially encountering the same error.