# conversion of .py to .exe using auto-py-to-exe showing error

Tags: python, pyinstaller, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I want to convert .py to .exe. For that I got to know that auto-py-to-exe is simple and works for Python >= 2.7 ( including 3.7  ). When I tried to convert a simple application it worked smoothly (auto-py-exe is working ) . But when I try to convert my original python scripts its throwing error:

```
An error occurred, traceback follows:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\lab_pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 35, in pywin32error
    yield
  File "c:\users\lab_pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
    return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)
  File "c:\users\lab_pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_dll.py", line 26, in _LoadLibraryEx
    function_name='LoadLibraryEx')
  File "c:\users\lab_pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_util.py", line 81, in __call__
    self._raise_error(function_name)
  File "c:\users\lab_pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_util.py", line 92, in _raise_error
    raise exception
OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Its my first time converting a code into .exe so I have no idea what to do now (excepting searching on web). I don't even know what is causing this error. I have doubt on mayavi but not sure. Anyhelp will be highly welcomed.

Program: python 3.7

GUI : PyQt5

Libraries included: mayavi,opencv,matplotlib,PIL,pylab,scipy,etc

Command to convert: pyinstaller -y  "path_to_script.py"

**Edits:**
I'm sure its due to mayavi as the simplest code attached didn't convert into .exe ( Sorry for lengthy post ! )
Its due to mayavi but I still want solution for this, Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi.mlab import contour3d
from mayavi import mlab

x, y, z = np.ogrid[-3:3:60j, -3:3:60j, -3:3:60j]

H1   =   0.45+x**2+y**2-z**2
obj1 = contour3d(H1, contours=[0], transparent=False)
mlab.show()
```

Command to convert: pyinstaller -y  "path_to_script.py"

Error:

```
An error occurred, traceback follows:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\lab_pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 35, in pywin32error
    yield
  File "c:\users\lab_pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
    return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)
  File "c:\users\lab_pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_dll.py", line 26, in _LoadLibraryEx
    function_name='LoadLibraryEx')
  File "c:\users\lab_pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_util.py", line 81, in __call__
    self._raise_error(function_name)
  File "c:\users\lab_pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_util.py", line 92, in _raise_error
    raise exception
OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\lab_pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\__main__.py", line 269, in convert
    pyi.run() # Execute PyInstaller
  File "c:\users\lab_pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\lab_pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\lab_pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 844, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\lab_pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 791, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\lab_pc\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_0mronij\stackoverflow_ask_py2exe.spec", line 17, in <module>
    noarchive=False)
  File "c:\users\lab_pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 243, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\lab_pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\lab_pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 567, in assemble
    redirects=self.binding_redirects))
  File "c:\users\lab_pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 231, in Dependencies
    for ftocnm, fn in getAssemblyFiles(pth, manifest, redirects):
  File "c:\users\lab_pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 407, in getAssemblyFiles
    for assembly in getAssemblies(pth):
  File "c:\users\lab_pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 358, in getAssemblies
    res = GetManifestResources(pth)
  File "c:\users\lab_pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winmanifest.py", line 1005, in GetManifestResources
    return winresource.GetResources(filename, [RT_MANIFEST], names, languages)
  File "c:\users\lab_pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winresource.py", line 168, in GetResources
    hsrc = win32api.LoadLibraryEx(filename, 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE)
  File "c:\users\lab_pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
    return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)
  File "c:\users\lab_pc\anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\users\lab_pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 37, in pywin32error
    raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (2, 'LoadLibraryEx', 'The system cannot find the file specified')

Project output will not be moved to output folder
Complete.
```

Should I use some different tool to convert? (Suggestions please in context to my problem).
Thanks

Comment: in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52775664/converting-gui-application-into-exe-file-with-cx-freeze-no-plugin-found-for-to) someone succeeded in producing a windows executable file by using `cxfreeze` instead of pyinstaller.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63762576/how-to-put-py-in-exe/63762944#63762944