# How to put .py in .exe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe

I have Python 3.6 and I did a project in .py that I would like to put in an .exe document ;
How can I do that ? I tried Py2exe but it did not worked due to my python version.
Thanks for your answers.

Traftmine

Comment: More duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-can-i-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependen, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136837/process-to-convert-simple-python-script-into-windows-executable, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059509/create-a-single-executable-from-a-python-project. And BTW the first is also for Python 3.6 so you should really try to search a little bit before posting a question

Answer (score 3):

I faced this problem some times ago, after a lot of googling I found the best solution for me.

### Alternatives

- [Py2Exe](https://www.py2exe.org/): Which is old, the last release on PyPi is on 21 October 2014.
- [pyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/): Is a nice tool, but with some problem that we will see later.
- [auto-py-to-exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/): Use pyInstaller to build the `.exe`, so suffer the same problem, but has a nice GUI and is intuitive to use.
- [cx_Freeze](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html): I think the best solution, because it was the only one that works in my case, it is also [recommended from python](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html)

### Investigation

During this time I looked on google and StackOverflow for the best solution, each time that I found something it was out-dated or not well explained/documented, so I studied the official docs.

#### py2exe

As first try I installed py2exe it seems the best option, also recommended from python, so, give it a try.
All goes fine during the installation process, so I decide to follow the [tutorial](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) and get my `.exe`.

During the step 3 of the tutorial, running setup I received an error, looking on google I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782117/py2exe-dll-load-failed).

I gave up with py2exe.

#### auto-py-to-exe && pyInstaller

I have installed auto-py-to-exe and all went good, the program open without problems so I create my `.exe` file, that works!

The only problem was that, the program works only on my laptop, on all the other machine where I try to execute the antivirus delete it.

Looking on google I found the [github repository](https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe) where I found one [issue](https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe/issues/16) like the mine, reading it I understand that the problem is pyInstaller.

Looking on the [pyInstaller repository](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller) I found one [issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4633) where one contributors tells to contact the antivirus vendor, so I gave up again.

#### cx_Freeze

Looking the [docs](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html) it seems to be overcomplicated realize a simple `.exe`, so I have studied the documentation and found what I need.

- Open you project folder and create inside it a `setup.py` file with inside:

  ```py
  from sys import executable
  from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

  setup(name='programName', version='0.1', description='my fancy description')
  ```

  Setting up this file require a little bit of study, there are multiple options to set. You can set the option to create a simple `.exe` or also the create a windows/mac/linux installer.
- Once you have your file ready, with the options that you need, just open a shell/terminal/cmd in the directory where the `setup.py` file is located and execute: `python setup.py build`
- Now in your project folder you will see a folder where inside you can find your `.exe` file.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).

Comment: Read about [answer]. Link-only answers are discouraged, especially when the question is not well-asked as well

Comment: @Tomerikoo: I think the question is clear and the answer is a package which solves the problem.

Comment: Both the question and this answer doesn't follow the guidelines of this website, found in the [help]. Specifically under [ask] and [answer].