# Pyinstaller Errno 22 Invalid argument:

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

Trying to convert one of my python files to an EXE for my friends to use with me.

IT worked earlier today. Changed nothing of substance and now im recieving the following error:

```
278151 ERROR: An error occurred while packaging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lewy1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\packaging.py", line 131, in package
    run_pyinstaller()
  File "C:\Users\lewy1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\lewy1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lewy1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 720, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Users\lewy1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 667, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\lewy1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpupp0c450\ProjectEXE.spec", line 20, in <module>
    exe = EXE(pyz,
  File "C:\Users\lewy1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 446, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\lewy1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\lewy1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 622, in assemble
    with open(exe, 'rb') as infh:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\lewy1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpupp0c450\\build\\ProjectEXE\\run.exe.db9ln703'
```

I noticed that when this error occurs windows defende pops up informing me 'Trojan
:Win32/Wacatac.D3!ml' I've never noticed this whilst using pyinstaller previously.

so my question is, does anyone know of any fixes for this issue?

Edit:
I have just selected onedir instead of onefile and it has worked. Hoping maybe this could help in the solving of the issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63762944/5532710

Comment: Thank you @CarloZanocco this gave me the ground research to find a work around! Although not Ideal i just dissabled windows anit virus temporarily and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Carlo's comment, it seemed to be evident that it was an antivirus issue. So disabling my antivirus whilst the exe was building did the trick!

Comment: You can also try another module to build the exe. With cx_Freeze I never had problems.

Comment: This was next on my list to try if my workaround didnt work. 
 I am keeping this in find for furture reference, if I keep having issues i will definitely swap!
Thank you for your help!