# Creating a .exe from 3 files

Tags: python, auto-py-to-exe

I have the following main script that calls using the subprocess function 2 scripts, the first one is a GUI and data process, and the second one deletes temporary files created by the first script.

```
import subprocess
import time

subprocess.call(["python","DataProcess.py"])
time.sleep(5)
subprocess.call(["python","DeleteFiles.py"])
```

I am trying to use the tool auto-py-to-exe, to create a single executable but I can not get it to work. When I run the executable the following error appears:

**python: can't open file 'DataProcess.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory**

I have been investigating and I think is because I'm not doing the references properly but I do not understand how to do them.

Do I need to add something to my code? Or am I missing some other configuration for auto-py-to-exe?

Comment: You'll have better luck invoking these using built-in Python mechanisms (is `import` followed by a function call an option?). Invoking a sub-interpreter just complicates everything without any real gain.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63762576/how-to-put-py-in-exe/63762944#63762944

Comment: How are you compiling your script?