# using pyinstaller with mayavi.mlab import

Tags: python, pyinstaller, mayavi.mlab

I would like to use *pyinstaller* to convert a python script containing "*from mayavi import mlab*" into an *.exe* file.

The python script *Test1.py* contains just one line code: *from mayavi import mlab*

By using the command *pyinstaller Test1.py*, I am able to convert the python script into an .exe file. But when I run the .exe file, I got the following error messages

```
    from mayavi import mlab
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_
importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\mayavi\mlab.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_
importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\mayavi\tools\camera.py", line 24, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_
importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\mayavi\tools\engine_manager.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_
importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\mayavi\preferences\api.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_
importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\mayavi\preferences\preference_manager.py", line 29, in <mo
dule>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_
importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\traitsui\api.py", line 36, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_
importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\traitsui\editors\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_
importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\traitsui\editors\api.py", line 24, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_
importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\traitsui\editors\code_editor.py", line 37, in <module>
  File "site-packages\traitsui\editors\code_editor.py", line 49, in ToolkitEdito
rFactory
  File "site-packages\traits\traits.py", line 655, in __call__
  File "site-packages\traits\traits.py", line 1414, in Color
  File "site-packages\traitsui\toolkit_traits.py", line 8, in ColorTrait
  File "site-packages\traitsui\toolkit.py", line 109, in toolkit
  File "site-packages\pyface\base_toolkit.py", line 281, in find_toolkit
  File "site-packages\pyface\base_toolkit.py", line 209, in import_toolkit
RuntimeError: No traitsui.toolkits plugin found for toolkit null
[8520] Failed to execute script Test1
```

Here in the following, you could find the packages, which I installed with pip:

```
Package         Version
--------------- ------------------
altgraph        0.16.1
apptools        4.4.0
asn1crypto      0.24.0
certifi         2019.3.9
cffi            1.12.3
chardet         3.0.4
conda           4.6.14
configobj       5.0.6
cryptography    2.6.1
cycler          0.10.0
envisage        4.7.1
future          0.17.1
idna            2.8
kiwisolver      1.1.0
macholib        1.11
matplotlib      3.1.0
mayavi          4.6.2
menuinst        1.4.16
mkl-fft         1.0.12
mkl-random      1.0.2
numpy           1.11.3
pefile          2019.4.18
Pillow          6.0.0
pip             19.1.1
pycosat         0.6.3
pycparser       2.19
pyface          6.1.0
Pygments        2.4.0
PyInstaller     3.5.dev0+d74052489
pyOpenSSL       19.0.0
pyparsing       2.4.0
PySocks         1.7.0
python-dateutil 2.8.0
pywin32         223
pywin32-ctypes  0.2.0
QtPy            1.7.1
requests        2.21.0
ruamel-yaml     0.15.46
scipy           1.2.1
setuptools      41.0.1
shiboken2       5.12.3
sip             4.19.8
six             1.12.0
traits          5.1.1
traitsui        6.0.0
urllib3         1.24.2
vtk             8.1.2
wheel           0.33.4
win-inet-pton   1.1.0
wincertstore    0.2
wxPython        4.0.6
```

I saw the question posted in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50337382/creating-standalone-exe-using-pyinstaller-with-mayavi-import), but did not understand how it works. I would rather use pyinstaller to convert a python script into an .exe file.

Comment: Have you tried `--hidden-import=mayavi.mlab` when using Pyinstaller?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
After using the command "pyinstaller
 --hidden-import=mayavi.mlab Test1.py", the .exe file can be generated. But when I execute the .exe file, I still get the same error as described above. 
(RuntimeError: No traitsui.toolkits plugin found for toolkit null
[6616] Failed to execute script Trail1)